# Understanding the offset method's return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

I have an element with `id="stimulus"` in an HTML document.

When I open this document in a browser and use the browser's console to investigate properties of `#stimulus`, this is what I see:

```
> $('#stimulus').offset()
< Object {top: 0, left: 0}
> $('#stimulus').css('top')
< "-155.761px"
> $('#stimulus').css('left')
< "253.087px"
```

How am I to interpret this?  How is `top` within `offset` different from `top` accessed using the `css` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [offset() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), offset is from the top of the document; whereas top and left css properties are relative to the parent. Perhaps you wish to look at [position(](http://api.jquery.com/position/)) to get the offset relative to the [offset parent](http://api.jquery.com/offsetparent/).

Comment: in my example, wouldn't that mean `#stimulus` should appear at the (0, 0) position of the whole document?  wouldn't that be the top-left corner of the page?  (that's not where `#stimulus` appears.)

Comment: @dbliss Is your element hidden, offset with padding, borders or margin? The documentation says it does not provide correct positions for special cases

Comment: @dbliss Why don't you provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue? It should then be obvious

Comment: at the time i accessed the values the stimulus was hidden, yes.  that explains it.  thanks.  i see that now in the documentation.  `position` has the same limitation.  `css('top')` does not seem to be so limited.

Comment: @dbliss browsers can't calculate dimensions or position for something they aren't having to paint into the page.

Comment: It should be noted it would be more obvious error in jq 3.x: [Error cases don’t silently fail](https://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/)

Answer (score 4):

Offset is the position within the whole page

css top will postion the element relative to it's closest positioned ancestor.
That ancestor could be anywhere in the page and so offset and top do not match unless there is no positioned ancestor

Answer (score 4):

You probably got that difference of results because `id="stimulus"` was being animated and you sended `console.log` in different frames. Or the element is in fact "static" and has some other properties that changes his `offset()` location.

Like

```js
console.log("Offset:", $('.test').offset()); // returns {top: 0, left: 0}
console.log("Top/Left:", $('.test').css('top'),  $('.test').css('left')); // returns -200px, -20px
```

```css
.test{
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  left: -20px;
  transform: translateY(200px) translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.offset()` method "returns the coordinates of the element relative to the document", whereas the `.css()` method returns whatever values have been applied via CSS styles.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery's `.offset()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

> The `.offset()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element *relative to the document*. Contrast this with `.position()`, which retrieves the current position *relative to the offset parent*.

The [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method abstracts the native [`CSSStyleDeclaration` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration), which returns the position relative to the parent element, **but only if it is explicitly specified in CSS**. So if you want that, then use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) instead of `.offset()`.

## Demo

```js
$(function() {
  var child = $('.child');

  console.log('offset: ', child.offset());
  console.log('position: ', child.position());
  console.log('css: ', {
    top: child.css('top'),
    left: child.css('left')
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Hello World</div>
</div>
```